# Using JS variables in Google Analytics Events

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

We're using gtag.js to set up event tracking with the following code inserted directly under `<head>`:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-nnnn-n"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-nnnn-n');
  gtag('event', 'event_name', {
  'event_category': categoryName,
  'event_label': labelName
});
</script>
```

Below on the index page we've got `onclick` events set up for various buttons and links. These have the following example format:

```
<li><a href="//a_link" class="btn btn-nav" 
onclick="gtag('event', 'menu', 
{ 'event_category': 'menu-link', 'event_action': 'open-menu', });">Link Text
</a></li>
```

In the Chrome console I'm getting the error message:

`(index): Uncaught ReferenceError: categoryName is not defined`

**Question**
Can we use variables like `categoryName` in such a way?

I've read Google documentation about gtag events but didn't find explicit mention of using variables.
Edit: Referring to the docs here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events

Comment: You're adding the events to the links via the onclicks. The event code in the tracking code snippet is looking for a strings for the event_category and event_label. The event code in the tracking code snippet itself is unnecessary.

Comment: @BronwynV Should I just delete that entire last gtag in the tracking code snippet then (the one defining `event`, `event_name`, etc.)?

Comment: I would delete it, it serves no purpose if you are adding the event tracking to your actual links/buttons.  If you were to configure an event and add it to the tracking code snippet itself as per your above example, then you would be sending an event along with each pageview.